# access parent state in children slot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My component in react js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const ComponentA = ({ children }) => {
  const [state1, setState1] = useState('Hello');
  const [state2, setState2] = useState('World');

  // Your component logic here
  return <div>{children}</div>;
};

export default ComponentA;
```

i need to use this method but not work but when use this  not show:

```
const YourComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ComponentA>
        {(state1, state2) => (
          <div>
            State 1: {state1}
            <br />
            State 2: {state2}
          </div>
        )}
      </ComponentA>
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```

How to resolve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### As a render prop:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const ComponentA = ({ children, render }) => {
  const [state1, setState1] = useState('Hello');
  const [state2, setState2] = useState('World');

  // Your component logic here
  return (
    <div>
     {children}
     {render(state1,state2)}
    </div>
  )

};

export default ComponentA;
```

And then you call pass a prop called render

```
const YourComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ComponentA render={(state1, state2) => (
          <div>
            State 1: {state1}
            <br />
            State 2: {state2}
          </div>
        )}>
        Some other children
      </ComponentA>
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-7xwcvm?description=A%20create-react-app%20project%20based%20on%20react%20and%20react-dom&file=src%2FApp.js&title=React%20Starter)

### As children:

You simply call the `children` prop:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const ComponentA = ({ children }) => {
  const [state1, setState1] = useState('Hello');
  const [state2, setState2] = useState('World');

  // Your component logic here
  return <div>{children(state1,state2)}</div>;
};

export default ComponentA;
```

And then you can do exactly as you did:

```
const YourComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ComponentA>
        {(state1, state2) => (
          <div>
            State 1: {state1}
            <br />
            State 2: {state2}
          </div>
        )}
      </ComponentA>
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```

It's a common pattern known as function-as-a-child or maybe better known as a render prop (in this case the `prop` is `children`)

EDIT:

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-7xwcvm?description=A%20create-react-app%20project%20based%20on%20react%20and%20react-dom&file=src%2FApp.js&title=React%20Starter) as an example

Comment: i get this error: children is not a function. i am using react v18.2

Comment: @Ameea then you're not doing something correctly, see the stackblitz edit in my answer

Comment: thanks. problem is i use another component in componentA slot like this:

 `<ComponentA>
        {(state1, state2) => (
          <div>
            State 1: {state1}
            <br />
            State 2: {state2}
          </div>
        )}
      <ComponentB />
      </ComponentA>`

Comment: Then pass component A a named prop that’s a function (aka a render prop) instead of passing the function as a child

Comment: Can you update your answer please?

Comment: @Ameea updated with a render prop example

Answer (score 0):

The most commonly found is the parent component passsing props to the children components since React JS shares data typically in a unidirectional. Please read [this article](https://dev.to/alexmercedcoder/react-data-flow-understanding-state-and-props-2759) for more insight into the data flow in React JS.

The work around as shown [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs/) would be to create a callback function and pass it to the child component.

Parent Component:

```
const YourComponent = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState("")
    
   function getValuesFromChild(state1, state2) {
      setValue(state1 + ' ' + state2)
   }

    return (
        <div>
          <ComponentA getValuesFromChild={getValuesFromChild}>
            {value && 
              <div>
                <p>{value}</>
              </div>
            }
          </ComponentA>
       </div>
      );
    };
```

ComponentA:

```
const ComponentA = ({ children, getValuesFromChild }) => {
    const [state1, setState1] = useState('Hello');
    const [state2, setState2] = useState('World'); 

    //Using useEffect just to send the data from the child
    useEffect(() => {
        getValuesFromChild(state1, state2)
    }, []) 

    // Your component logic here
    return <div>{children}</div>;
};
```

Honestly, I have no idea why you would want to do it this way but well, the above solution works. You could use other methods such as passing props from the parent component or simply creating a context too.

Comment: i know that. it's a different method.